# Create table and add rows / remove rows using Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, return, fetch

I would like to ask for help to make the code below more dynamic.

HTML code:

```
<div id="table1"></div>
```

Javascript code:

```
let headers = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];

let formElements = [
    { elementTyp: 'text', id: 'oneID', name: 'oneName', css: 'form-control', placeholder: 'onePLC' },
    { elementTyp: 'select', url: 'https://api.frankfurter.app/latest', id: 'twoID', name: 'twoName' },
    { elementTyp: 'select', url: 'https://api.frankfurter.app/latest', id: 'threeID', name: 'threeName' },
    { elementTyp: 'text', id: 'FourID', name: 'fourName', css: 'form-control',  placeholder: 'fourPLC' }
];


createTable("table1", "listTable", "addIDS", headers);

document.getElementById("addIDS").addEventListener("click", () => { addNewRow("listTable", formElements); }, false);

function addNewRow(tableIDS,formElements) {
    let listTable = document.getElementById(tableIDS);
    let tableBody = listTable.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    
    formElements.forEach(emp => {
        let cell = document.createElement('td');
        
        if(emp.elementTyp == "text" || emp.elementTyp == "checkbox") {
            const formInputElem = createFormElem(emp.elementTyp, emp.id, emp.name, emp.css, emp.placeholder);
            
            console.log(formInputElem);
            
            cell.append(formInputElem);
        }
        
        if(emp.elementTyp == "select") {
            const formSelectElem = selectCreateElem(emp.url, emp.name, emp.id);
            
            cell.append(formSelectElem);
            selectView(tableIDS);
        }
        
        row.appendChild(cell);
    });
    
    let cell = document.createElement('td');
    
    let addBtn = document.createElement('input');
    addBtn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    addBtn.setAttribute('value', '-');
    addBtn.setAttribute('onClick', 'deleteRow("'+tableIDS+'",this)');
    addBtn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-danger btn-sm');
    cell.appendChild(addBtn);
    
    row.appendChild(cell);
    tableBody.appendChild(row);
}


function deleteRow(tableIDS, rowsID) {
    const tableID = document.getElementById(tableIDS);
    
    tableID.deleteRow(rowsID.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);
}


function createFormElem(type, id, name, css, placeholder) {
    let inputText = document.createElement('input');
    inputText.setAttribute('type', type);
    inputText.setAttribute('id', id);
    inputText.setAttribute('name', name);
    inputText.setAttribute('class', css);
    inputText.setAttribute('placeholder', placeholder);
    
    return inputText;
}


function selectCreateElem(url, name, id) {
    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        
        const selectEL = document.createElement("select");
        selectEL.setAttribute('name', name);
        selectEL.setAttribute('class', "form-select rounded-0");
        selectEL.setAttribute('id', id);
        
        const currencies = Object.entries(data.rates).forEach(([code, value]) => {
            const optionEl = document.createElement("option");
            optionEl.value = code;
            optionEl.text = value;
            selectEL.appendChild(optionEl);
        });
        
        return selectEL;
        
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

const formSelectElem returns a function whose value I want to attach to the cell.append(formSelectElem). But that doesn't work.

How could I place the form elements generated by the function in the table cell?

I would like the code to be more transparent.

That is why it would be important to be able to solve the form elements with a function call.

Comment: its already a function. Please explain what you need?

Comment: At the moment, I am not creating the form elements with functions.    if(emp.elementTyp == "text") and if(emp.elementTyp == "checkbox") and if(emp.elementTyp == "select")  I would like to solve the parts in between with functions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.